# throwable will not compile

Tags: java

First I must say that I read the following:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html!

The error I get when I try to compile is the following:

```
TestException.java:14: error: incompatible types

static void doRisky(String test) throws ScaryException
                                                ^
required: Throwable
found:    ScaryException

TestException.java:19: error: incompatible types
                        throw new ScaryException();
                                      ^
required: Throwable
found:    ScaryException

TestException.java:34: error: incompatible types
                catch ( ScaryException  se)
                        ^
  required: Throwable
  found:    ScaryException

3 errors
```

I'm assuming that the error message is giving me some type of hint, but I just don't see what it is.

```
import java.lang.*;
/** add this as to get it to compile */
class ScaryException extends Exception
{
/** how come I can't put code here? */
}

public class  TestException {

    static void doRisky(String test) throws ScaryException{
        System.out.println ("start risky");    
        if ("yes".equals(test)) {
            throw new ScaryException();
        }
        System.out.println("end risky");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        String test = "no";
        try{
            System.out.println("start try");
            doRisky(test);
            doRisky("yes");
            System.out.println("end try");
        }
        catch ( ScaryException  se){
            System.out.println("Got What " + se);
        }
        finally{
            System. out. println( "finally") ;
        }

        System.out.println("end of main");
    }
}
```

Comment: does your `ScaryException` extend a subclass of throwable? usually a  `java.lang.Exception`?

Answer (score 2):

Java exceptions must extend `Throwable` (either directly, or preferably indirectly by extending `Exception` or one of its subclasses).  Apparently your `ScaryException` class doesn't.

Comment: The easiest way would be to add "extends Exception" onto the definition of `ScaryException`, like `class ScaryException extends Exception`.  Assuming, of course, that you haven't gone and done something wacky with it like reinvent exception handling.  :)

Answer (score 1):

For this to compile, `ScaryException` must be a class that extends `Throwable` or one of its subclasses. Either `ScaryException` doesn't exist at all, or it doesn't extend any of `Throwable`'s children.